# Gridview Date Formatting

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have Gridview to show all the data from a datatable.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
                    AllowPaging="True" Width="100%" PageSize="20"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="true" 
                    CssClass="applicationList-grid" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" EmptyDataText="No Data!">

</asp:GridView>
```

and the gridview binded by

```
 string sql = "SELECT * from ApplicationForm";
        DataTable dt = GetDataTable(connectionString, sql);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }
```

There is some date fields. The date showing like 04/03/2014 00:00:00 in gridview. I want to format the date with only date no time.

I just try `dataformatstring="{MM/dd/yyyy}` but it is not working.

Comment: why not check your database, and set that ,I think its `DateTime` in your database and just set it to `Date` only?

Comment: Give a shot! `DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"`

Answer (score 3):

You can convert it by below usage-

```
<span><%# Eval("columnname", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")</span>'
```

**Or in SQL**

```
CONVERT( VARCHAR(10), "columnname" ,110)
```

Note- `110` is the country code.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this inside your `<asp:GridView>`

```
<asp:boundfield datafield="Date_Column" dataformatstring="{0:MMMM d, yyyy}" htmlencode="false" />
```

Make sure that HtmlEncode is set to False, otherwise it will not work

Comment: Hi SimonGA  the AutoGenerateColumns="true" .Then how can we use this <asp:boundfield>

Comment: You cannot use that when AutoGenerateColumns="True". You will need to do it in the databound event of the gridview.
You can also do it directly via SQL (please see Manojs answer)

Answer (score 2):

put :

```
DataFormatString="{0:MM-dd-yyyy}"
```

and :

```
htmlencode="false"
```

on your bound field tag. You can see the format which you want.